# How to get the InputNumber name in antdesign for react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working with antdesign for ReactJS.

My code looks like this:

```
<InputNumber
    formatter={value => `${value} hrs`}
    parser={value => value.replace(' hrs', '')}
    type="text"
    onChange={props.changed}
    name='hours'
    min={0}
    max={24}
    defaultValue={8} />
```

changehandler:

```
  changeHandler = (event, id) => {
     console.log(event + ' ' + typeof event);
     console.log(event.target.name + ' ' + typeof event.target.name);
  }
```

So far, I have tried looking around for this and seems like others have come across the same issue: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8683

The console log in my `changeHandler` fxn returns a number and undefined for the second line.

How can I get the name?

Comment: `onChange` handler for `InputNumber` only gets you the changed value

Comment: for the normal `Input` field, I am able to get the entire event, allowing me to access the name by using `event.target.name`

Comment: yes, on change handler for `Input` gives you `event` as argument, `InputNumber` however doesn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[onChange](https://ant.design/components/input-number/) only gets the value that was changed

You can use a curried function here.

```
  changeHandler = name => value => {
     console.log(name, value);
  };

  <InputNumber
    onChange={this.changeHandler("hours")}
  />
```

Comment: Finally got it to work. I want to learn more about what you did there. Should I look for curried functions?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend it. "name => value =>" is short form  of  changeHandler = name => {
    return value => {
      console.log(name, value);
    };
  };

Answer (score 1):

If you use normal function instead of an arrow function as change handler, the `this` inside that function will be the `event.target` and you can get `name` as well as `value` from `this`. However you wont be able to access `this` for the react class so you will have to use function closure to store the value of `this` for react class.

```
<InputNumber
    formatter={value => `${value} hrs`}
    parser={value => value.replace(' hrs', '')}
    type="text"
    onChange={props.changed(this)}
    name='hours'
    min={0}
    max={24}
    defaultValue={8} />

  changeHandler(reactThis){
    var classThis=reactThis;//use classThis to access this pointing to react class
    return function(value){
      console.log(this.name,this.value,value);//will print name, current value and changed value
      //classThis.setState({}) will work here
    };
  }
```

And in the this